# Loss function volatility with TF/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

Im running a rather simple Keras classification, based on 30 features. What I dont get to understand yet is why the loss function gets way more volatile if I increase the number of rows going into the model:

```
df = pd.read_csv("cancer_classification.csv")
df = df.iloc[:50]

# split data
X = df.drop("benign_0__mal_1", axis=1).values
y = df["benign_0__mal_1"].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.50, random_state=101)

# scale
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
scaler.transform(X_test)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

print(X_train.shape)
# ---> (50, 30)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(15, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(5, activation="relu"))

# binary classification - so last layer has sigmoid activation function
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")

# we will overfit to show how it looks like - so 1000 epochs
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

# plotting it out - we leave out first 10 rows so we dont skew chart too much with high loss number on the beginning
loss_df = pd.DataFrame(model.history.history)

loss_df = loss_df.iloc[10:]
loss_df.plot()
plt.show()
```

The original idea was to visualize overfitting when loss keeps dropping while val_loss starts to rise. I wonder why putting 500 rows creates such wild oscilations in the loss functions.

[50 df rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxrj3.png)

[500 df rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X3RO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to shuffle your data. And check the number class distribution for the first 50 rows and for the 500 rows I think this might be a consequence of not shuffling. It can also be caused by the features you are getting into your model.